# Adding an empty row to the datatable at the end when reading excel and fill to the datatable

Tags: c#

I have read excel file using OLEDB and fill into datatable. Everything is fine but when I delete each cell of each column in excel file using delete button from keyboard, an empty row gets added to the data table after read. But when I delete entire row by select, the problem does not reproduce.

If anyone knows the solution please let me know.

I  used below connection string

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1\"";
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to ignore empty rows? -> that should be fairly easy when you have the datatable via code or what is your desired behaviour?

Comment: yes..I want to remove empty row.